# Spring batch : how to use create two two steps in one job

Tags: java, spring-batch, jobs

I've a one class that I use to create two different Beans. These two Beans are then used to create two Steps and these two steps must be executed in sequence.
I use one class to create two beans because the logic to be executed is the same. By passing different values in the constructor, the data to be fetched is different.

But when Spring-batch is running, an IllegalStateException exception is thrown:
What causes this exception to be thrown ?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.stepBrussels': Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:383)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:195)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.getName(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.isStepRestart(JobFlowExecutor.java:86)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for step scope
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.getContext(StepScope.java:167)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371)




@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class InstrumentReaderConfig {

    @Value("${chartinvest.url.admin}")
    private String adminUrl;

    @Value("${eodHistoricalData.url.listOfTickers}")
    private String listOfTickerslUrl;

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<TickerDto> itemReaderBr() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return new InstrumentReader(adminUrl, listOfTickerslUrl, "XBRU", "BR", "BE");
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<TickerDto> itemReaderAs() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return new InstrumentReader(adminUrl, listOfTickerslUrl, "XAMS", "AS", "NL");
    }

}



@Configuration
public class StepConfig {

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ItemReader itemReaderBr;

    @Autowired
    private ItemReader itemReaderAs;

    @Autowired
    private ItemProcessor itemProcessorEodHistorical;

    @Autowired
    private ItemWriter<TickerDto> itemWriterEodHistorical;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Step stepBrussels() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("Brussels").<TickerDto, TickerDto>chunk(1)
                .reader(itemReaderBr)
                .processor(itemProcessorEodHistorical)
                .writer(itemWriterEodHistorical)
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Step stepAmsterdam() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("Amsterdam").<TickerDto, TickerDto>chunk(1)
                .reader(itemReaderAs)
                .processor(itemProcessorEodHistorical)
                .writer(itemWriterEodHistorical)
                .build();
    }
}


@Configuration
public class JobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;


    @Bean
    public Job processJob(Step stepBrussels, Step stepAmsterdam, JobExecutionListener listener) {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("processJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(stepBrussels)
                .next(stepAmsterdam)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove @StepScope from your step beans, @StepScope is only for beans used in steps, not steps themselves

Comment: I removed  @StepScope  from the Step, and added onto the Bean creation. Now the Exception is gone.